# I need to pass an integer to a function that only accepts arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function

Had a question regarding functions and arrays. Suppose i have this

```
int example1(unsigned int hold[], size)
 {
   ....
 }
```

and then in another function i want to call my example 1 function but  instead of passing an array i want to pass an integer, so like this

```
int example2(unsigned int hold)
{
  int i;

 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    example1(hold,i);
}
```

how would i make it work

Comment: Write another function that accepts only one integer? Your question and your intent are not clear.

Comment: So in the second code block, is your intent to pass `hold` as a one-element array? In that case it would seem your call should be `example1(&hold, 1);`. Or are you trying to create an `i`-element array with one element containing the value from `hold`? Or are you trying to create an `i`-element array with all elements being set to `hold`? Please EDIT THE QUESTION using the `edit` button just below the tags - do NOT put additional info into comments, where it will probably be overlooked - and clarify what it is you're attempting to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Your `example1` function takes a pointer to the first element of an `int` array.  Since a pointer to a single variable is essentially equivalent to a pointer to the first element of an array, you can just pass the address of that single `int` with a size of 1:

```
example(&hold, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd put it the other way around.  The OP's function *does not* receive an array argument in the first place.  This is a misconception on the OPs part, albeit a common one.  The function receives a pointer.  There's no inherent difference between a pointer to a scalar `int` variable and a pointer to an element of an `int` array.

Answer (score 5):

A pointer to value can be passed in place of an array of only 1 element; your loop makes `example1` assume an array of size more than 1.

Since you are passing `i` as the size, make an array of `i` elements, set it up with some values, and pass it to `example1`, like this:

```
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    unsigned int arg[i+1];
    for (size_t j = 0 ; j != i ; j++) {
        arg[j] = value;
    }
    example1(arg, i);
}
```

Comment: This is the only viable solution give `example1` function definition. Passing `&i, 1` would not be passing an array (the fact that an array is converted to a pointer when passed as a parameter is a red-herring here)

Comment: @chux Right... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In C99, you can also use [compound literal](https://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#6.5.2.5):

```
example1((unsigned int[]){hold}, 1);
```